# static_transform_publisher doesn't latch on ROS2

Tags: ros, ros2, static-transform-publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On `Noetic`, I can do the following:

```
$ run tf2_ros static_transform_publisher 1 1 1 0 0 0 f1 f2 &
[2] 1753768
[ INFO] [1639635211.900468919]: Spinning until killed publishing f1 to f2
$ rostopic echo /tf_static 
transforms: 
  - 
    header: 
      seq: 0
      stamp: 
        secs: 1639635211
        nsecs: 900398326
      frame_id: "f1"
    child_frame_id: "f2"
    transform: 
      translation: 
        x: 1.0
        y: 1.0
        z: 1.0
      rotation: 
        x: 0.0
        y: 0.0
        z: 0.0
        w: 1.0
```

This is exactly what I expect to happen since the static publisher is latched.

However, on `Galactic` using `CycloneDDS`:

```
$ ros2 run tf2_ros static_transform_publisher --x 1 --y 1 --z 1 --frame-id f1 --child-frame-id f2 &
[1] 213102
1639635686.858624 [0] static_tra: selected interface "lo" is not multicast-capable: disabling multicast
[INFO] [1639635686.868694587] [static_transform_publisher_GjMa6BC7irM5FXBs]: Spinning until stopped - publishing transform
translation: ('1.000000', '1.000000', '1.000000')
rotation: ('0.000000', '0.000000', '0.000000', '1.000000')
from 'f1' to 'f2'
$ ros2 topic echo /tf_static 
1639635697.443620 [0]       ros2: selected interface "lo" is not multicast-capable: disabling multicast
```

No output is produced, but `ros2 topic` keeps waiting. I'm using `loopback` as our routers don't like multicast, but since it can find the topic `/tf_static` shouldn't it also be able to find the message since it uses the `durability` policy `transient local`? Or am I misunderstanding something?

I also found [this GitHub bug report](https://github.com/ros2/geometry2/issues/183) that suggests:

```
ros2 topic echo --qos-durability transient_local /tf_static
```

However, that fails in the same way as above for me.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/392875/static_transform_publisher-doesn%27t-latch-on-ros2/) by [KenYN](https://answers.ros.org/users/25651/kenyn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 541 on 2021-12-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KenYN](https://answers.ros.org/users/25651/kenyn/) on 2021-12-16**:
I've [raised a bug on GitHub](https://github.com/ros2/geometry2/issues/487) too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had tried:

```
ros2 topic echo --qos-durability transient_local /tf_static
```

But [GitHub told me](https://github.com/ros2/geometry2/issues/487#issuecomment-995799117) that I also need `--qos-reliability reliable`, so now the following works as expected:

```
ros2 topic echo --qos-durability transient_local --qos-reliability reliable /tf_static
```

---

Originally posted by [KenYN](https://answers.ros.org/users/25651/kenyn/) with karma: 541 on 2021-12-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0